# Prove that $\tan^{-1}{\frac{1}{5}} \approx \frac{\pi}{16}$ using complex number method

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

> Prove that $\tan^{-1}{\frac{1}{5}} \approx \frac{\pi}{16}$ using
>   complex number method.
>
> Hint: Take $z=5+i$

What is meant by complex number method in this problem? I couldn't think of do the above proof using complex numbers. Any suggestions ?

Comment: In fact we have $\pi/16 = \arctan(1/5) - {1 \over 4} \arctan({1 \over 239})$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$(5+i)^4 = 476 + 480i $ Since $476$ is approximately $480$, the angle of the line from $0$ to $476 + 480i$ made with the x-axis is about $45$ degrees or $\pi/4$ radians.

So $\arctan (1/5) $ is about $\pi/4 \over 4$ or $\pi/16$.

Answer (score 3):

We may notice that 
$$ (5+i)^8 = -3824 + 456960 i \tag{1} $$
is a complex number relatively close to the imaginary axis. By applying $\text{arg}$ to both sides of $(1)$,
$$ 8\arctan\frac{1}{5}\approx \frac{\pi}{2} \tag{2} $$
follows.

Answer (score 1):

Using Binomial and De Moivres’ Theorem , we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
\cos (4 \theta)+i \sin (4 \theta) = & (\cos \theta+i \sin \theta)^4 \\
= & \cos ^4 \theta+4 i \cos ^3 \theta \sin \theta-6 \cos ^2 \theta \sin ^2 \theta -4 i \cos \theta \sin ^3 \theta+\sin ^4 \theta
\end{aligned}
$$
Comparing their real and imaginary parts, we get formula for $\cos (4\theta) $ and $\sin (4\theta)$ and yields $$
\begin{aligned}
\tan (4 \theta) & =\frac{4 \cos ^3 \theta \sin \theta-4 \cos \theta \sin ^3 \theta}{\cos ^4 \theta-6 \cos ^2 \theta \sin ^2 \theta+\sin ^4 \theta} \\
& =\frac{4 \tan \theta-4 \tan ^3 \theta}{1-6 \tan ^2 \theta+\tan ^4 \theta}
\end{aligned}
$$
Now let $\theta=\tan^{-1} \frac{1}{5}  $ and get
$$
\begin{aligned}
\tan (4 \theta) & =\frac{4\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)-4\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)^3}{1-6\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)^2+1\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)^4} \\
& =\frac{120}{119} \\
& \approx 1 \\
\Rightarrow &  4 \theta \approx \frac{\pi}{4} \\
\Rightarrow &\tan^{-1} \frac{1}{5} \approx \frac{\pi}{16}
\end{aligned}
$$
Wish it helps!